# "Undefined" in the end of the accumulator.value()

Tags: javascript, function, constructor

I ran into the problem of the value misplacement in the `constructor` `function` `method` `this.result`. I do not understand why I'm get the result of the end of the `function` - `undefined`...

Tell me please, what is forgotten to include in the `function` :(

```
function Accumulator(startingValue) {
    this.startingValue = startingValue;

    this.read = function() {
        this.a = +prompt('Your digit: ', '');
    };

    this.value = function() {
        this.value += this.a;
    };

    this.result = function() {
        return this.value + this.startingValue;
    }
}

var accumulator = new Accumulator(1); // starting value 1
accumulator.read(); // sum prompt with current value
accumulator.read(); // sum current prompt with previous prompt and current value
console.log( accumulator.result() ); // display sum result
```

Comment: Is `accumulator.value` supposed to be an integer or a function?

Comment: @bergi  to be an integer

Comment: Then don't define it as a function :-) I think you should drop `.value()`, `.startingValue` and `.a` and just use `.value` everywhere. Put the summation directly into the `read` method.

Comment: return the value

Comment: `read` does nothing unless you call `value`, and value is undefiened so you can't `undefined + 1212`

Comment: @bergi Maybe we have misunderstanding )
In the result - method value() of accumulator must display an integer value.

Comment: @SviatKuzhelev Isn't the `.result()` method doing that? There should not be a *call* to `.value()` anywhere

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `.value` is supposed to be an integer, don't define it as a function :-)

I think you should drop `.value()`, `.startingValue` and `.a` and just use `.value` everywhere. Put the summation directly into the `read` method. Simplify to:

```
function Accumulator(startingValue) {
    this.value = startingValue;

    this.read = function() {
        // the temporary variable might be unnecessary but I left it in for verbosity
        const a = +prompt('Your digit: ', '');
        this.value += a;
    };

    this.result = function() {
        return this.value;
    };
}

var accumulator = new Accumulator(1); // starting value 1
accumulator.read(); // add prompt to current value
accumulator.read(); // add another prompt to current value
console.log( accumulator.result() ); // display sum by calling result() method
```

You might also want to define the methods on the prototype:

```
function Accumulator(startingValue) {
    this.value = startingValue;
}
Accumulator.prototype.read = function() {
    this.value += +prompt('Your digit: ', '');
};
Accumulator.prototype.result = function() {
    return this.value;
};
```

and even use modern `class` syntax, as @ArtificialBug suggested:

```
class Accumulator {
    constructor(startingValue) {
        this.value = startingValue;
    }
    read() {
        this.value += parseInt(prompt('Your digit: ', ''), 10);
    }
    result() {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh... Now I see what I had miss. Thanks a lot buddy! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems

```
this.value = function() {
    this.value += this.a; //this.value is a function
};
```

and

```
 console.log( accumulator.value ); // accumulator value is a function which needs to be invoked
```

Make it

```js
function Accumulator(startingValue) {
    this.startingValue = startingValue;

    this.read = function() {
        this.a = (this.a || this.startingValue ) + +prompt('Your digit: ', '');//initialize and add the prompted value
    };

    this.value = function() {
        return this.a; //simply return the value
    };

    this.result = function() {
        return this.a + this.startingValue; //this.a instead of this.value
    }
}

var accumulator = new Accumulator(1); 
accumulator.read(); 
accumulator.read(); 
console.log( accumulator.value() ); // invoke the method
```